# JavaDoc: Reduce redundancy for Repeated Method Descriptions within the Same Class

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, javadoc, block-comments

For example, i have two methods, `public Tree<T> addChild(final T data) {}` and `public Tree<T> addChild(final T... data) {}`, their JavaDocs are identical. How to put the `/** method description */` in one of them, and use a tag to refer another JavaDoc to the previous one?

Just like, in concept:

```
/**
 * method description
 */
public Tree<T> addChild(final T data) { ... }

/**
 * @theTag #addChild(Object)
 */
public Tree<T> addChild(final T... data) { ... }
```

If i remember it correctly, i once accidentally came across a tag, which imports the entire method description of a Java native API method. So, it should be possible.

What is `@theTag`? Thanks very much!

Comment: You are probably thinking if `@inheritDoc`, which does not do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

How's about @see tag? It's not quite importing, but rather placing a reference:

```
/**
 * action 1 description
 */
public void action1(){}

/**
 * @see MyClass#action1
 */
public void action2(){}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But `@see` is just having a link in the bubble. It is not good enough :-/

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing better in bare javadoc. Only {@inheritDoc} copies the entire description, but it only works for implemented or overriden methods.

Comment: OH yes!! The one i came across was `/* (non-Javadoc) * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object) */ @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) { ... }`. i have just tried that pattern for a while, and it seems only work for inherited methods, as you said.